# Updating a pointer to a c array from a function

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

Say I have a function called `array_push` in c.

```
void array_push(int *array_pointer, int array_length, int val) {
    int i;
    int *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (array_length + 1));

    for (i = 0; i < array_length; i++) {
        temp_array[i] = *array_pointer;
        array_pointer++;
    }

    temp_array[array_length] = val;
    *array_pointer = temp_array;
}
```

How can I update the pointer `*array_pointer` so that it points to `temp_array` and other parts of my program can use the new array? Allowing me to do something like

```
int t[2] = {0,2};
array_push(t, 2);
/* t should now contain {0,2,3} */
```

Comment: You can't do this. `t` is not a pointer, it's an array, you can't change the size of an array.

Comment: @Barmar - you're absolutely correct.  I didn't notice that part of the OP's question at first...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to turn `array_pointer` into a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void array_push(int **array_pointer, int array_length, int val) {
```

(note the extra asterisk).

Also, you'll need to change the call site so that `t` is a pointer, not an array (you can't make an array point someplace else). Finally, to make the caller aware of the new size of the array, `array_length` also needs to be passed by pointer.

Thus, the overall structure of your code could be something like:

```
void array_push(int **array_pointer, int *array_length, int val) {
    int *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (*array_length + 1));
    memcpy(temp_array, *array_pointer, sizeof(int) * *array_length);
    temp_array[(*array_length)++] = val;
    free(*array_pointer);
    *array_pointer = temp_array;
}

int main() {
    int n = ...;
    int* t = malloc(sizeof(int) * n);
    /* ... */
    array_push(&t, &n, 2);
    /* ... */
    free(t);
}
```

Note how I've allocated `t` on the heap, and have freed `*array_pointer` inside `array_push()`. With this in mind, much of the `array_push()`'s logic can be simplified by using `realloc()`:

```
void array_push(int **array_pointer, int *array_length, int val) {
    *array_pointer = realloc(*array_pointer, sizeof(int) * (*array_length + 1));
    (*array_pointer)[(*array_length)++] = val;
}
```

Comment: you reinvented `realloc()`.

Comment: @Barmar: I know. I am working my way towards it (the answer is still work in progress).

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems here: You seem confused about pass-by-value, but the more significant problem is that you seem confused about pointers. `int *array_pointer` array_pointer points to an `int`, not an array. It may be that it points to the first `int` in an array. On an unrelated note, a "pointer to an int array" looks like: `int (*array_pointer)[array_length]`.

Back to the point: `int *array_pointer` array_pointer points to an `int`. In `*array_pointer = temp_array;`, the expression `*array_pointer` gives you the object pointed to, which can store an `int`. `temp_array` isn't an `int` value, though.

I can see that you're attempting to work around the issue that changes made to `array_pointer` aren't visible to the caller, due to the semantics of pass-by-value. Hence, you need to change `array_pointer` so that it points to an `int *` that the caller supplies, so that you're modifying the caller's `int *`, or use the return type to return the new pointer. As it turns out, both of these options solve both of your problems.

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM 1:

If you want to create or modify an *int array inside of a function, then you need to pass a "pointer to a pointer":

```
// WRONG:
void array_push(int *array_pointer, int array_length, int val) {
...
    int *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (array_length + 1));
...
    *array_pointer = temp_array;
```

Instead:

```
// BETTER:
void array_push(int **array_pointer, int array_length, int val) {
...
    int *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (array_length + 1));
...
    *array_pointer = temp_array;
```

Or:

```
// BETTER YET:
int * array_push(int array_length, int val) {
...
    int *temp_array = malloc(sizeof(int) * (array_length + 1));
...
return temp_array;
```

PROBLEM 2:

If you want to declare a static array like this `int t[2] = {0,2};`, then you can't arbitrarily change it's size.  Here's a good description of "arrays vs pointers":

> http://faq.cprogramming.com/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1069897882&id=1073086407
>
> One of the first things a new student learns when studying C and C++
>   is that pointers and arrays are equivalent. This couldn't be further
>   from the truth...